MimeMessage-attachment too short if readAllBytes
When reading the attachment of a mail-message (B64 encoded) I face a problem.
 MimeMessage mm = ...
 if (mm.getContentType ().contains ("multipart") == true)
 {  
    MultiPart mp = (MimeMultipart) mm.getContent ();
        
    for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount (); i ++)
    {
        MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) mp.getBodyPart (i);
        String ct = mbp.getContentType ();  
        
        String fn = mbp.getFileName ();
        
        InputStream is = mbp.getInputStream ();
        byte [] bs = is.readAllBytes ();
        ...

readAllBytes only reads 8192 bytes. But should be > 1MB.
If I go byte-wise, it reads all bytes.
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
 int c;
 while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
 {
     baos.write (c);
 }
                    
 byte [] bs = baos.toByteArray ();

What I found is this.
https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api/issues/408
But that's 5 years ago - a possible bug should be fixed now.
Does anyone have a hint for me, thx!
EDIT
Tried as suggested:
byte [] bs;
try (InputStream is = mbp.getInputStream ())
{
    bs=is.readAllBytes();
}

Did not make a change - still only 8k instead of > 1MB.
EDIT
Runing it on OpenJDK11 and
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

This is because I use mail-functions of BouncyCastle and I think they are not completely ready for jakarta.mail.

Try try-with-resources .byte [] bs = null; try (InputStream ... { read all bytes } Better than flush

Ah. Try a flush too

Can you try and create a [mre]? What's the content of MimeMessage mm?

Probably a good idea to save an offending message as an eml file and post a link to it

I think it would be worth mentioning which version of Jakarta Mail (and, I guess, Angus Mail), you are using. However I’m afraid you might have to debug this one.

Replace the while is.read with is.transferTo(baos); in a try, to close.

The bug was closed as fixed four years ago. Read the last entry by @BillShannon.

Can you give me maybe a link or something? Thanks a lot. I am not sure where to find what you are mentioning. Thanks!

Bouncy supports the (newer) Jakarta-mail API using bcjmail.jar instead of bcmail.jar since 1.69 in 2021; see e.g. https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcjmail-jdk18on .

@dave_thompson_085 - I think this info is GOLD! THX

The link is yours, in your question. See the last entry at the bottom of the page.

The bug you linked in the question was closed by this commit in Jakarta Mail 1.6.5 in 2020.
You are using Javax Mail 1.6.2 (from 2018!) which does not have the fix. Migrate to Jakarta Mail and you will have the fix.

I tried that but was not able to get BouncyCastle work with Jakarta-Mail. I use it for some Mail-security-topcis. Maybe I give it another try. Thx!

There is bcjmail available for that, see bc-java#832 – but if you are having trouble with that you should ask a separate question.
